# SML: get element from the list

Tags: list, sml

Question about Standard ML (SML).
Is it possible to get an element from the list by using the row and column index? Something like this:

```
myList = [(1,9,3),(3,5,5),(7,0,1)]
myList[1,2] // 1st row 2nd column => in this case 9
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a good idea to think in terms of "rows" and "columns", but yes, you can do what you describe, by writing this:

```
#2 (List.nth (myList, 0))    (* 0th element, component #2 -- in this case 9 *)
```

`List.nth` is part of [the Standard ML Basis Library](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/); it maps from `'a list * int` to `'a`. In this case `List.nth (myList, 0)` is `(1,9,3)`. (Note that it uses zero-based indexing.) `#2` is a built-in part of the language, referring to the `2`-labeled component of a record (such as, as in this case, the second component of a tuple).